# Debugging an XNA application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, xna, draw

I am having trouble debugging my XNA application, using VS 2010 ultimate and XNA GameStudio 4.0.
When I set a breakpoint inside one of the Draw methods and the execution hits the breakpoint, the whole application freezes, goes "not responding" and I can't switch to back to VS until I kill the process from Task Manager.
Is this innate to the way the Draw method works in XNA or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks for an answer

Comment: I can say that this isn't innate behavior. You should be able to debug without issue. I don't really have any suggestions as to what could be wrong though - is your app running full screen?  I've had that cause some strange behavior when trying to debug.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running fullscreen, gonna try change to windowed mode.

Comment: OK, that's the correct answer. Fullscreen mode messes things up, windowed mode is running correctly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Feel free to flag @John's answer as the correct one. My comment was mostly a random guess:)

Comment: If you have a second monitor, put VS (or the game) on the other monitor when you debug. Windowed mode is easier, but if you want to keep it as a full screen game, this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run XNA in windowed mode. This can be done with some code like this when you load the game:

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);     // "this" being your Game class
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1024;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

(edit: sorry for not reading the comments above)